# calculate-binomio-newton

Tags: calculus, binomial-coefficients

i am help

Calculate:

$$(C^{16}_0)-(C^{16}_2)+(C^{16}_4)-(C^{16}_6)+(C^{16}_8)-(C^{16}_{10})+(C^{16}_{12})-(C^{16}_{14})+(C^{16}_{16})$$

PD : use  $(1+x)^{16}$ and binomio newton

Comment: Three answers have appeared (including mine) but so far I'm the only one who's up-voted the question. This often gets neglected. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy De-Facto "self-centeredness" at its worst...I'll down vote because I think the question has no context, but I didn't answer the question so...

Comment: @Zach466920 : Your first phrase above lost me.  Do you mean the poster is self-centered, or that I am, or that the others who answer are, or what? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael No, actually it was a comment on the weird rationalization that some people, clearly not you, go through to justify answering a question they feel is badly written, not worthy of upvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
(C^{16}_0)-(C^{16}_2)+(C^{16}_4)-(C^{16}_6)+(C^{16}_8)-(C^{16}_{10})+(C^{16}_{12})-(C^{16}_{14})+(C^{16}_{16})
$$

$$
1,0,-1,0,\overbrace{1,0,-1,0}^{\text{This repeats}\ldots},\ldots
$$

Powers of the imaginary number $i$ are:
$$
1,i,-1,-i,\overbrace{1,i,-1,-i}^{\text{This repeats}\ldots},\ldots
$$
So our first repeating sequence is just the sequence of **real parts** of our second repeating sequence.  Thus we want the real part of
\begin{align}
& C^{16}_0 i^0 + C^{16}_1 i^1 + C^{16}_2 i^2 + \cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & (1+i)^{16} = \Big( \sqrt 2 \ e^{i\pi/4} \Big)^{16} = 2^8 e^{4i\pi} = 256\cdot 1.
\end{align}

This number is real, and so equal to its own real part.

Answer (score 4):

Put $x=i$ and find the real part of $(1+i)^{16}$

Can you finish this?

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative way:**

Note
\begin{align*}
(C^{16}_0)-(C^{16}_2)+(C^{16}_4)-(C^{16}_6)+(C^{16}_8)-(C^{16}_{10})+(C^{16}_{12})-(C^{16}_{14})+(C^{16}_{16})&=\text{Re}\left((1+i)^{16}\right)\\
&=\text{Re}\left((2i)^{8}\right)\\
&=\text{Re}\left((-4)^{4}\right)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: why $Re((1+i)^{16})=Re((2i)^8) $

Comment: Since $i^{2k}$ is a real number provided $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate it as follows instead of calculating combinatorics

$${ \left( 1+i \right)  }^{ 16 }={ \left( { \left( 1+i \right)  }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ 8 }=\left( 1+2i-1 \right) ^{ 8 }={ \left( 2i \right)  }^{ 8 }=256$$